# Pass Django variables between view functions

Tags: python, django

I'm asking a question about variables handling in my `Django` application view.

I have 2 functions :

- The first one lets me to `display query result` in an array with `GET filter parameter` (in my case, user writes year and Django returns all objects according to this year. We will call `query_naissance` this variable).
- The second one lets me to create a `PDF`. I have lots of variables but I want to take one more time `query_naissance` in my PDF.

This is my first function :

```
@login_required
def Table_annuelle_BirthCertificate(request) :

    query_naissance = request.GET.get('q1')
    ...
    return render(request, 'annuel.html', context)
```

And my second function looks like :

```
@login_required
def Table_Naissance_PDF(request) :

    data = {"BirthCertificate" : BirthCertificate}

    template = get_template('Table_raw.html')
    html  = template.render(Context(data))

    filename = str('Table annuelle Naissance.pdf')
    path = '/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/Individus/' + filename


    file = open(path, "w+b") 
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file, encoding='utf-8')
    file.close()

    context = {
        "BirthCertificate":BirthCertificate,
        "query_naissance":query_naissance,
    }

    return render(request, 'Table.html', context) # Template page générée après PDF
```

So How I can add `query_naissance` given by user in my first function to my second one without write one more time a field ?

Then, I have to call this variable like `{{ query_naissance }}` in my HTML template.

Thank you

Comment: Ok I am making some researches about value storing in the session.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I just have to see why my variable doesn't display on my PDF but your script seems to work ;) Please add an answer in order to valide it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to persist information across requests, you would use sessions. Django has very good [session support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/):

```
# view1: store value
request.session['query_naissance'] = query_naissance

# view2: retrieve vlaue
query_naissance = request.session['query_naissance'] 
# or more robust
query_naissance = request.session.get('query_naissance', None)
```

You need `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.