# Rendering Received Webhook Payload by Django Views

Tags: python, django, session, django-views, webhooks

**Dev Platform:**

- Python 3.6.2
- Django 3.0
- Windows 10 VScode

> **Problem:**
>
> I'm not able to render the received webhook payload on the
>   django template via same view method or by redirect. Also I'm not able to use django sessions variable to pass payload data to another view. Seems like no session exist as per the print statements. Looks like I'm missing something cirtical.

**Details:**
settings.py
My sessions middleware and installed app settings are properly set as well for cookie based sessions.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
```

I've configured my webhook url on mailchimp after exposing my local dev server using ngrok.
For example

> 34nghirt345.ngrok.io/webhook

and also in my url config as follows:

**urls.py**

```
path('webhook/', views.my_webhook_view),
path('webhook/<str:some_id>/', views.webhook_renderer, name ="url_webhook_renderer"),
```

I'm receiving webhook payload from mailchimp at the configured url path and is able to process the payload within the respective view method.

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_webhook_view(request):
    # Mailchimp webhook receiver for mailchimp batch operations.
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Webhook Payload Received')
        logger.debug(f"Some ID: {request.POST.get('data[id]')}")
        payload_dict = {k:v for k,v in request.POST.items()}
        logger.debug(f"Dict of POST DATA: {payload_dict}")
        context = {
            'some_id': payload_dict['data[id]']
        }
        print("Webhook Post session items Before: ",request.session.items())
        request.session["context"] = context
        request.session.modified = True
        # I have also used SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True as well but that didn't work either.
        print("Webhook Post session items After: ",request.session.items())

        #return render(request, "webhooks/webhook_rendering.html", context = context)
        return redirect('url_webhook_renderer', batch_id = context['some_id'])

def webhook_renderer(request, batch_id):
    print("Webhook rendering session passed context:",request.session.get('context'))
    print("Webhook rendering session items:",request.session.items())
    context = request.session.get('context')
    return render(request, "webhooks/webhook_rendering.html", context = context)
```

**Console Output:**

Prints statements form my_webhook_view

> Webhook Post session items Before:  dict_items([]) Webhook Post
>
> session items After:  dict_items([('context', {'batch_id':'some_id'})])

Print statements from webhook_renderer

> Webhook rendering session passed context: None
>
> Webhook rendering session items: dict_items([])

**webhook_rendering.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <p> {{ some_id }} </p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django views are *stateless*, meaning that each `request` you receive, knows nothing of other request objects.  The `request` object in `my_webhook_view` is a completely different object than the `request` object in `webhook_renderer`, and any attributes you set on one will not be accessible in the other.

If you want access to data received from your webhook, you will need to save the data to your database, or a cache, or both.

Comment: @ Monica. After doing some research for passing data between views people suggested to use django sessions middleware. Are you suggesting its not correct procedure. e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763115/django-passing-data-between-views and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111303/pass-django-variables-between-view-functions

Comment: @FarhanS in this context, it doesn't make sense to use sessions.  The `session` for the webhook view pertains to mailchimp, while the `session` for the rendering view pertains to the end user.